# What are the possible values pairwise parameter in GridSearchV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm breaking my head with a parameter error (pairwise) in GridSearchV.
I'm tranning a model using ELMClassifier using GridSearchV as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
ELM = ELMClassifier()
param={'alpha': [100, 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001],
       'n_neurons': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
       'ufunc': ['sigm', 'tanh', 'relu']}
ELM_reg = GridSearchCV(ELM, param, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5)
```

When I run this code, the following error is thrown:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter pairwise_estimator for estimator ELMClassifier(alpha=100, n_neurons=50). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

When I run this code, it's throwing an exception asking for "pairwise" parameter, however I don't know what are the possible values for this parameter, even in documentation.

What the possible values and what's the concept of this parameter?

Comment: This is documented in [`skelm.ELMRegressor`](https://scikit-elm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skelm.ELMRegressor.html).

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: Please post the full error trace, as well as all relevant **imports** - where does `ELMClassifier` come from? See how to create a [mre].

Comment: If your code is actually representative, I suspect `skelm` has not properly implemented the sklearn API.